# Ember select ValueBinding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a controller like this,

```
 App.ViewerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
          selectedUsers: [],
          users: null
});
```

users gets filled at the route.

However when i declare a select multiple in my template,

```
{{view Ember.Select
contentBinding="controller.users"
multiple="true"
class="input-large"
valueBinding="controller.selectedUsers"
optionLabelPath="content.userId"
optionValuePath="content.userId"
}}
```

the selectedUsers is not selected in the view. what am i doing wrong? I capture this from the Ember Inspector
for `selectedUsers` right before the Ember.Select is called,

```
0: "Irshu"
1: " Yehuda"
@each: (...)
get @each: function () {
set @each: function (value) {
__ember1389253247784_meta: Meta
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
```

But once Ember.Select is called, `selectedUsers` is then undefined. Am i missing something?Please help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `selection` option.  [updated bin](http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2984/edit)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get 'selectedUsers'. For example, if you are using the selection in an action in your controller, then you would access the selection with `this.get('selectedUsers')`, like this:

```
App.ViewerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   selectedUsers: ['George'],
   users: ['George', 'Samantha', 'Miguel'],
   actions: {
     yourAction: function(){
       console.log(this.get('selectedUsers'))
       // the rest of your action here
     }
   }
});
```